# how to check if there are duplicate timestamps and add one separate them by one second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have data with thousands of points. It records timestamps of when 100 people do a certain recurring activity in a day. It records everything in minute level so there are duplicates in the data.

I want to index my timestamp column, but I cant do it because there are duplicate timestamps.
I want to separate duplicates by second so that I can index them.

How would I go about it?

```
timestamp        
2022-10-10 01:05:00
2022-10-10 01:05:00
2022-10-10 01:23:00
...
```

I want to add 1 second to either one of the duplicate values.

Comment: yeah sorry, i mean to put 2022.

Answer (score 3):

You can de-duplicate using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df['timestamp'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('timestamp').cumcount(), unit='s')
```

output:

```
            timestamp
0 2022-10-10 01:05:00
1 2022-10-10 01:05:01
2 2022-10-10 01:23:00
```

used input:

```
            timestamp        
0 2022-10-10 01:05:00
1 2022-10-10 01:05:00
2 2022-10-10 01:23:00
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great for what I asked, but it turns out I need to use minute level data. So, I need to add 1 minute instead of 1 second to duplicates. But, when the +1 minute is added, then that'll likely create some new duplicates. how do i deal with that?

Comment: @prof31 I don't know your data of the background, **you** should decide ;)

Comment: This does not work for me or anymore: "TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with TimedeltaArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`" - Any fix?